# Using Symfony Guard for login consistently gives my "Invalid Credentials"

Tags: php, symfony, authentication, doctrine-orm

Followed the Symfony documentation as best I could. I've tried all forms of encoding algorithms, and the the guard interface simply does not want to log any users in. Does anyone see what I am doing wrong here?

Here's all the code

The login part of the controller:

```
namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AuthenticationException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

class SecurityController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @param $name
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
     * @Route("/login", name="login")
     */
    public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {
        $user = $this->getUser();

        if($user instanceof UserInterface) {
            return $this->redirectToRoute('homepage');
        }

        return $this->render('AppBundle:Security:index.html.twig', array(
            'error' => $this->get('security.authentication_utils')->getLastAuthenticationError(),
            'last_username' => $this->get('security.authentication_utils')->getLastUsername()
        ));
    }
}
```

security.yml

```
security:
    providers:
        in_memory:
            memory: ~

    encoders:
        AppBundle\Entity\User: sha512

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        main:
            anonymous: ~
            logout:
                path: /logout
                target: /
            guard:
                authenticators:
                    - form_authenticator
                entry_point: form_authenticator

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

The Doctrine User Entity:

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * Class User
 * @package AppBundle\Entity
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Entity\UserRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="users")
 */
class User implements UserInterface, \Serializable {
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="UUID")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100)
     */
    private $username;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100)
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $password;

    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @Assert\Length(max=4096)
     */
    private $plainPassword;

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set username
     *
     * @param string $username
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setUsername($username)
    {
        $this->username = $username;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get username
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getUsername()
    {
        return $this->username;
    }

    /**
     * Set email
     *
     * @param string $email
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setEmail($email)
    {
        $this->email = $email;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get email
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    /**
     * Set password
     *
     * @param string $password
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setPassword($password)
    {
        $this->password = $password;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get password
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    /**
     * String representation of object
     * @link http://php.net/manual/en/serializable.serialize.php
     * @return string the string representation of the object or null
     * @since 5.1.0
     */
    public function serialize()
    {
        return serialize(array(
            $this->getId(),
            $this->getUsername(),
            $this->getEmail(),
            $this->getPassword()
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Constructs the object
     * @link http://php.net/manual/en/serializable.unserialize.php
     * @param string $serialized <p>
     * The string representation of the object.
     * </p>
     * @return void
     * @since 5.1.0
     */
    public function unserialize($serialized)
    {
        $id = $this->getId();
        $username = $this->getUsername();
        $email = $this->getEmail();
        $password = $this->getPassword();

        list(
            $id,
            $username,
            $email,
            $password
            ) = unserialize($serialized);
    }

    /**
     * Returns the roles granted to the user.
     *
     * <code>
     * public function getRoles()
     * {
     *     return array('ROLE_USER');
     * }
     * </code>
     *
     * Alternatively, the roles might be stored on a ``roles`` property,
     * and populated in any number of different ways when the user object
     * is created.
     *
     * @return (Role|string)[] The user roles
     */
    public function getRoles()
    {
        return array(
            'ROLE_USER'
        );
    }

    /**
     * Returns the salt that was originally used to encode the password.
     *
     * This can return null if the password was not encoded using a salt.
     *
     * @return string|null The salt
     */
    public function getSalt()
    {
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Removes sensitive data from the user.
     *
     * This is important if, at any given point, sensitive information like
     * the plain-text password is stored on this object.
     */
    public function eraseCredentials()
    {
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPlainPassword()
    {
        return $this->plainPassword;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $plainPassword
     */
    public function setPlainPassword($plainPassword)
    {
        $this->plainPassword = $plainPassword;
    }
}
```

The repository for the User entity:

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Security\User\UserLoaderInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\UsernameNotFoundException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

class UserRepository extends EntityRepository implements UserLoaderInterface {

    /**
     * Loads the user for the given username.
     *
     * This method must return null if the user is not found.
     *
     * @param string $username The username
     *
     * @return UserInterface|null
     */
    public function loadUserByUsername($username)
    {
        $user = $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
            ->where('u.username = :username')
            ->setParameter('username', $username)
            ->getQuery()
            ->getOneOrNullResult();

        return $user;
    }
}
```

The login form twig:

```
{% extends 'AppBundle::base.html.twig' %}

{% block mainContent %}
    {% if error %}
        <div>{{ error.messageKey|trans(error.messageData, 'security') }}</div>
    {% endif %}

    <form action="{{ path('login') }}" method="post">
        <label for="username">Username/Email:</label>
        <input type="text" id="username" name="username" value="{{ last_username }}">

        <label for="password">Password:</label>
        <input type="password" id="password" name="password">

        <button type="submit">Login</button>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

services.yml

```
parameters:

services:
    form_authenticator:
        class: AppBundle\Security\FormAuthenticator
        arguments: ['@router', '@service_container']
```

...and finally the authencator:

```
namespace AppBundle\Security;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouterInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AuthenticationException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\CustomUserMessageAuthenticationException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\UsernameNotFoundException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Security;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\InMemoryUserProvider;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserProviderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Guard\AbstractGuardAuthenticator;

class FormAuthenticator extends AbstractGuardAuthenticator {

    /**
     * @var RouterInterface
     */
    private $router;

    /**
     * @var ContainerInterface
     */
    private $container;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $failMessage = 'Chris says you are not valid.';

    public function __construct(RouterInterface $routerInterface, ContainerInterface $containerInterface)
    {
        $this->container = $containerInterface;
        $this->router = $routerInterface;
    }

    /**
     * Returns a response that directs the user to authenticate.
     *
     * This is called when an anonymous request accesses a resource that
     * requires authentication. The job of this method is to return some
     * response that "helps" the user start into the authentication process.
     *
     * Examples:
     *  A) For a form login, you might redirect to the login page
     *      return new RedirectResponse('/login');
     *  B) For an API token authentication system, you return a 401 response
     *      return new Response('Auth header required', 401);
     *
     * @param Request $request The request that resulted in an AuthenticationException
     * @param AuthenticationException $authException The exception that started the authentication process
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function start(Request $request, AuthenticationException $authException = null)
    {
        $url = $this->router->generate('login');

        return new RedirectResponse($url);
    }

    /**
     * Get the authentication credentials from the request and return them
     * as any type (e.g. an associate array). If you return null, authentication
     * will be skipped.
     *
     * Whatever value you return here will be passed to getUser() and checkCredentials()
     *
     * For example, for a form login, you might:
     *
     *      return array(
     *          'username' => $request->request->get('_username'),
     *          'password' => $request->request->get('_password'),
     *      );
     *
     * Or for an API token that's on a header, you might use:
     *
     *      return array('api_key' => $request->headers->get('X-API-TOKEN'));
     *
     * @param Request $request
     *
     * @return mixed|null
     */
    public function getCredentials(Request $request)
    {
        if($request->getPathInfo() != '/login' || !$request->isMethod('POST')) {
            return;
        }

        return array(
            'username' => $request->request->get('username'),
            'password' => $request->request->get('password'),
        );
    }

    /**
     * Return a UserInterface object based on the credentials.
     *
     * The *credentials* are the return value from getCredentials()
     *
     * You may throw an AuthenticationException if you wish. If you return
     * null, then a UsernameNotFoundException is thrown for you.
     *
     * @param mixed $credentials
     * @param UserProviderInterface $userProvider
     *
     * @throws AuthenticationException
     *
     * @return UserInterface|null
     */
    public function getUser($credentials, UserProviderInterface $userProvider)
    {
        if(!$userProvider instanceof InMemoryUserProvider) {
            return;
        }

        dump($userProvider->loadUserByUsername($credentials['username'])); die();
        try {
            return $userProvider->loadUserByUsername($credentials['username']);
        } catch(UsernameNotFoundException $e) {
            throw new CustomUserMessageAuthenticationException($this->failMessage);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns true if the credentials are valid.
     *
     * If any value other than true is returned, authentication will
     * fail. You may also throw an AuthenticationException if you wish
     * to cause authentication to fail.
     *
     * The *credentials* are the return value from getCredentials()
     *
     * @param mixed $credentials
     * @param UserInterface $user
     *
     * @return bool
     *
     * @throws AuthenticationException
     */
    public function checkCredentials($credentials, UserInterface $user)
    {
        $plainPassword = $credentials['password'];
        $encoder = $this->container->get('security.password_encoder');

        if(!$encoder->isPasswordValid($user, $plainPassword)) {
            throw new CustomUserMessageAuthenticationException($this->failMessage);
        }

        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Called when authentication executed, but failed (e.g. wrong username password).
     *
     * This should return the Response sent back to the user, like a
     * RedirectResponse to the login page or a 403 response.
     *
     * If you return null, the request will continue, but the user will
     * not be authenticated. This is probably not what you want to do.
     *
     * @param Request $request
     * @param AuthenticationException $exception
     *
     * @return Response|null
     */
    public function onAuthenticationFailure(Request $request, AuthenticationException $exception)
    {
        $request->getSession()->set(Security::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR, $exception);
        $url = $this->router->generate('login');

        return new RedirectResponse($url);
    }

    /**
     * Called when authentication executed and was successful!
     *
     * This should return the Response sent back to the user, like a
     * RedirectResponse to the last page they visited.
     *
     * If you return null, the current request will continue, and the user
     * will be authenticated. This makes sense, for example, with an API.
     *
     * @param Request $request
     * @param TokenInterface $token
     * @param string $providerKey The provider (i.e. firewall) key
     *
     * @return Response|null
     */
    public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token, $providerKey)
    {
        $url = $this->router->generate('homepage');

        return new RedirectResponse($url);
    }

    /**
     * Does this method support remember me cookies?
     *
     * Remember me cookie will be set if *all* of the following are met:
     *  A) This method returns true
     *  B) The remember_me key under your firewall is configured
     *  C) The "remember me" functionality is activated. This is usually
     *      done by having a _remember_me checkbox in your form, but
     *      can be configured by the "always_remember_me" and "remember_me_parameter"
     *      parameters under the "remember_me" firewall key
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function supportsRememberMe()
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: This "I've tried all forms of encoding algorithms" sound likes you are just randomly trying things.  That seldom ends well.  Add some dump or die statements to your guard and verify it is being called.  That should give you a starting point.  But most importantly, take a break and think about what you are doing.  Otherwise you will just keep chasing your tail.  Been there. Done that.

Comment: I've tried this many times. It's very hard for me to decipher where in the code I should implement these dumps. So far all the ones I've tried produce expected results, with no exceptions or errors. At which point should I output the results of invalid credentials in the authenticator?

Comment: If you have not already, add hide_user_not_found: false to app/config/security.yml.  That should at least tell you if it is the username or the password failing. Verify if checkCredentials is being called and is returning true.  Verify if onAuthenticationSuccess is being called.